# Can I Attach a Label to a SKNode?

Tags: ios, swift, button, sprite-kit, sknode

I am creating a game that needs to have a label be attached to a node because I am using it as a button and the button moves around. Does anyone know how to attach a label to a SpriteKit node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `SKLabel`, you can use that

```
let scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
scoreLabel.text = "Score: 0"
scoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .right
scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 980, y: 700)
addChild(scoreLabel)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to investigate parent and child nodes in SpriteKit. your label will end up being an SKLabel and a child nod of your button. Thus it will move, scale, rotate etc with its parent.